# nginx php array variable in url

Tags: php, nginx

I'am struggling with using php array variables in request url, then using some rules in nginx which would decide if url should be sent to php backend or 404 returned, here is an examle:

I want link www.mypage.com/search?q=abc to return 404 with the help of nginx
but link www.mypage.com/search?q[q]=abc to be passed to php backend

This is what I tried:

```
location /search {
  if ($arg_q ~ ".*"){
    return 404;
  }
}
```

All this does is returns 404 in either cases.

Comment: did you try to add another condition to exclude the `q[q]` case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another approach: to check `$args` on containing `q` without `[q]`:

```
location /search {
  if ($args ~ "\bq="){
    return 404;
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks.
didn't think of checking the whole $args for that